# change button images in PSPDFKIT

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, ios6, pspdfkit

I'm working on `PSPDFKIT`,

I want to change default button images.

and I want to change frame settings.

can anyone suggest me solving those problem

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Image from this code, here I am changing the image activityButton.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *myActbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.activityButtonItem.target action:self.activityButtonItem.action];

self.leftBarButtonItems = @[backBarButton,myActbutton,self.outlineButtonItem,self.brightnessButtonItem,self.searchButtonItem];


//self.leftBarButtonItems = @[backBarButton,self.activityButtonItem,self.outlineButtonItem,self.brightnessButtonItem,self.searchButtonItem]; your original code
```